# How can I get or create the equivalent of numpy's amax function with rust's ndarray crate?

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, rust

I want to get or create `numpy`'s `amax` functionality in Rust with the `ndarray` crate. So basically, I want to be able to get this behaviour in Rust:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array(range(1, 28)).reshape((3, 3, 3))
>>> np.amax(arr, axis=1)
array([[ 7,  8,  9],
       [16, 17, 18],
       [25, 26, 27]])
```

As far as I can see, there's no `amax` function in `ndarray`. How can I get the same functionality as mentioned in the above example with this `ndarray` array:

```rust
let arr = Array3::from_shape_vec((3, 3, 3), (1..28).collect()).unwrap();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `map_axis` and `min`

```
let a_min = arr.map_axis(Axis(0), |view| *view.iter().min().unwrap() )
```

You can see a working example in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b42040a1b155eba3c01cf0b7cd11a340)

Comment: Thanks. In my case it'll be `max`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fold_axis` as well:

```rust
let arr = ndarray::ArcArray1::range(1.0, 28.0, 1.0).reshape((3, 3, 3));
let arr2 = arr.fold_axis(ndarray::Axis(1), f64::NEG_INFINITY, |m, &v| m.max(v));

println!("{:?}", arr2)
```

This prints:

```
[[7.0, 8.0, 9.0],
 [16.0, 17.0, 18.0],
 [25.0, 26.0, 27.0]], shape=[3, 3], strides=[3, 1], layout=Cc (0x5), const ndim=2
```