# How do you get the maximum value from a rust ndarray?

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

Unlike NumPy ndarrays in Python, the arrays provided by the rust [ndarray](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/) crate do not seem to have `max` [method](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#methods-for-all-array-types) (or `min`, `argmax` or `argmin`) for that matter. What is the best way to get the maximum value from such an array (assuming it can be `f32` and `f64` rather than just integer types)?

```rust
use ndarray::Array

pub fn main() {
    let x = Array::from(vec![-3.4, 1.2, 8.9, 2.0]);

    // get max?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ndarray-stats](https://docs.rs/ndarray-stats/latest/ndarray_stats/index.html) crate provides the [`QuantileExt`](https://docs.rs/ndarray-stats/latest/ndarray_stats/trait.QuantileExt.html) traits for ndarray's, which provides a `max` method (and `min`, `argmax` and `argmin`), e.g.,

```rust
use ndarray::Array
use ndarray_stats::QuantileExt

pub fn main() {
    let x = Array::from(vec![-3.4, 1.2, 8.9, 2.0]);

    // get max
    let maxvalue = x.max().unwrap();

    println!("The maximum value is {}", maxvalue);
}
```

Comment: Note that there are no equivalents to apply this along a given axis currently.

Comment: Indeed. For multi-dimensional arrays it will just return the single overall maximum, otherwise you need something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/62547757/1862861 (although as that question/answer used integer's they were able to use the iterator's max/min method).